# Error cuando trato de asignar un valor a una llave en un dict Python-Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estoy haciendo una función y estoy sacando unos valores del request. Hice una variable de respuesta el cual tiene 3 nodos para llenarse.
Esta es la función

```
from django.http import HttpResponse as hres
import json

def go( req ):
    res = {
        'success':'',
        'message':'',
        'data':'',
    }

multiple = req.POST['mult']
value = req.POST['value']
if multiple is True and value == '':
    res.success = False
    res.message = 'No llegó el valor a buscar'
    res.data = None
else:
    res.success = True
    res.message = 'Se buscó correctamente'
    res.data = None
return hres( json.dumps( res ) )
```

Me aparece este error

> AttributeError at fakePath 'dict' object has no attibute 'success'

No lo entiendo, de hecho solo había declarado así mi variable

```
res = {}
```

Según yo mientras la key no exista en el primer nivel el mismo sistema la crea (O de menos así pasa en Javascript)

¿Que estoy ignorando?

Comment: En python las claves de un diccionario se acceden así: `diccionario['clave']`, y no así `diccionario.clave`, pues esto último es para atributos de objetos. En javascript son intercambiables, pero en python no.

Comment: Si lo hubieras hecho respuesta, ya te hubieras llevado una palomita D: Gracias por la aclaración